# how to mask decrypted input field in cakephp 3

Tags: encryption, cakephp-3.0, form-fields, data-masking

I want to store users' encrypted Social-Insurance-Number(SIN) in database and decrypt & display it as     `***-***-***` on users' edit page. I am using beforeSave and beforeFind functions in Model file for encryption and decryption. It works fine. But how can I display the decypted SIN as     `***-***-***` on edit page?

Comment: You want it to literally have the value `***-***-***` in the input field? But, presumably, if that value is submitted, you don't want to overwrite the real value in the database. Is your intent to have the real decrypted value in the field, just not visible to the user, or to not have that value there and do special handling server-side when `***-***-***` is submitted?

Comment: @GregSchmidt  I do not want the decrypted value there, I don't want someone to see that value when inspect. I want to do special handling server-side when `***-***-***` is submitted.
In controller, just before saving, I added a condition to check if  SIN value is `***-***-***` , if it is true, unset that field. I tried this and it is working, is this a good way ?

Comment: That sounds fine. To display that value, then, I think you just need to use `'value' => '***-***-***'` when you create the edit control for that field.